# Load the Script tag in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

I am using the react-native-render-html to load all the tags in view. but in my case script tag was not loaded.

Can anyone please let me know how to load the script tag inside the react native view.

I am getting the response data as follows. for every API response, url will be changed:

`"<script>window.location.replace(\"https://www.google.com\");</script>\r\n"`

or can you please let me know how to get only url and stored into variable.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 6.0.5, accessing script tags is not yet available. You can upvote this feature in React Native Render HTML official Canny: https://native-html.canny.io/features/p/support-script-tags